# Report to an error tracking service a Future unhandled exception when using the FutureBuilder widget

Tags: flutter, sentry

Following [flutter documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/maintenance/error-reporting) I have implemented in a flutter app a global strategy for managing unhandled exceptions:

```
Future<Null> main() async {
  // This captures errors reported by the Flutter framework.
  FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails details) async {
    if (isInDebugMode) {
      // In development mode simply print to console.
      FlutterError.dumpErrorToConsole(details);
    } else {
      // In production mode report to the application zone to report to
      // Sentry.
      Zone.current.handleUncaughtError(details.exception, details.stack);
    }
  };

  // This creates a [Zone] that contains the Flutter application and stablishes
  // an error handler that captures errors and reports them.
  //
  // Using a zone makes sure that as many errors as possible are captured,
  // including those thrown from [Timer]s, microtasks, I/O, and those forwarded
  // from the `FlutterError` handler.
  //
  // More about zones:
  //
  // - https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.2/dart-async/Zone-class.html
  // - https://www.dartlang.org/articles/libraries/zones
  runZoned<Future<Null>>(() async {
    runApp(new CrashyApp());
  }, onError: (error, stackTrace) async {
    await _reportError(error, stackTrace);
  });
}
```

When I use the FutureBuilder widget and associated Future throws an exception, this one is considered handled, and the Error text will be displayed:

```
 FutureBuilder<Post>(
        future: _post,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Post> snapshot)   {
          return snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done
              ? snapshot.hasData
                  ? _buildRoot(snapshot.data)
                  :  const Text('error')
              : const Text('loading...');
        })
```

My issue here is that the exception is considered as handled and will never been sent to `onError` callback in `runZoned` function.

Do you have any suggestion about sending the exceptions in the future to the global exception handler when using the `futureBuilder` widget?

Comment: Have you got any solution for this? @ilBarra